# I want to display a pokemon image that I get from the API, but I only get the url of the image and I don't know how to do it

Tags: javascript, image, api, vue.js, url

I'm new to programming and need some help.
I successfully get a random pokemon from the API and get its data: id, name and picture.
The most important thing for me is to show the image of that pokemon in the modal I made.
The problem is that I get the url of the image and I don't know how to display it[image]

In addition, I would like someone to help me so that when I enter the name of that pokemon in the input, it can check for me and if it is identical, I have some kind of alert or message feedback that I guessed.
Thank you very much in advance

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7hVn.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7hVn.jpg)

This is function in store.js to get one Pokemon from Api :

```js
async getOnePokemon() {
      try {
        let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 151) + 1;
        let response = await axios.get(`${apiLink}/pokemon/${id}`)
        if(response.data){
          let pokemon = {
            id: response.data.id,
            name: response.data.name,
            image: response.data.sprites.front_default
          }
          return pokemon
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
```

this is function that I call to get pokemon from store.js:

```js
async function GetPokemons() {
  try {
    let response = await PokemonStore.getOnePokemon();
    pokemonId.value = response;
    
    console.log(pokemonId.value)
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

this is header component where i have my modal where I want to show the image of pokemon where is {{ pokemonId.image }}

```html
<el-dialog v-model="game" title="Who's that pokemon?" width="35%" height="50%" center>
          <div class="modalHeader">
            {{ pokemonId.image }}
          </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="inputDiv">
                    <input class="pokeNameInput" type="text" placeholder="Search pokemon" />
                </div>
                <span>
                    <el-button id="submitBtn" @click="LogInModalVisible = false">Submit</el-button>
                    <el-button id="skipBtn" @click="LogInModalVisible = false;">Skip
                        <el-icon class="el-icon--right"><ArrowRight /></el-icon></el-button>
                    <el-button id="pokedexGameBtn" @click="LogInModalVisible = false">Pokedex</el-button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </el-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in img tag

```
<img :src="pokemonId.image" />
```

Comment: thank you. do you know how to do this: I would like when I enter the name of that pokemon in the input, it can check for me and if it is identical, I have some kind of alert or message feedback that I guessed.

Comment: You are welcome! I'll need more information about your question. If you want to check if you already have the pokemon that you found you need to store your founded pokemons in the backend. So for example your account have like 5 pokemons, what you can do is loop over and check if the founded pokemon exists in that loop.